# How to check if multiple files exists in azure container

Tags: azure-storage, exists, not-exists

To check if single blob exists in azure container we have below solution,

```
public bool DoesFileExistsInContainer(string fileName, string containerName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("File name to be moved is empty");
            }
            CloudBlobContainer containerReference = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = containerReference.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            bool isFileExist = blob.Exists();                
            return isFileExist;
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError("error while checking if blob exists : {0}" + ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But I want to check if multiple files do exists in azure container or not?

string[] filesToSearchInBlob = {"file1.xml", "file2.xml", "file3.xml"};

IS there an efficient way to check other than in foreach loop.. ? 
using LINQ? can we do it in better way?

Thanks in advance

Vinu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a more efficient way than `foreach` loop. If you do think performance is a concern, you may consider invoking `Exists` method simultaneously.

Comment: If the number of blobs is small, you could also retrieve a list of all blobs and run the loop on that. This may be more efficient than making multiple calls over the internet.

Comment: thanks.. since the blobs would grow with time, i would go with Exists approach.